# Does there exist a .NET XPath 'diff' command for two XmlDocuments?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath

I have a catalog processor I've built that updates itself by evaluating an xml based manifest file for the current state and comparing it to the local manifest.xml.

I currently process every node to look for a difference in some of the attributes to determine if an update needs to occur. I loop through every node in the tree.

I was wondering if there was a more optimized XPath or similar way to do a 'diff' on the 2 XmlDocuments and have it return all of the nodes that are different so I can only process those.

This is a .NET 2.0 C# application.

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used Xml Diff Patch in the past, have a look: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302294.aspx

Comment: Thanks! - this sounds like it is exactly what I am looking for!

Answer (score 0):

There is no additional help you are going to get from XPath.  To acheive this sort of thing I would get the editing application to assist.  I've built systems where I've added an attribute to a node indicating whether it has been **updated**, **added** or is to be **deleted**.  I then cascade up the tree ensuring the each ancestor is marked **dirty** (unless already marked as one of these other states).

To post changes the XML is processed with XSL selecting all nodes with any such state on.  A **dirty** node will have its attributes copied but only children with a state will be selected.  Utlimately you end up with some XML which only contains changed items and a state indicate what change is to be applied.  If concurrency management is needed I prefer to use a version number attribute.